# Oracle Trigger update column in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have table called `M_StockCode_JB` . Its fields are `Code`, `Description`, and `Display`.

Display is still empty, but Code and Description has values as the following :

```
  M_StockCode_JB
-----------------------
Code    |   Description
1       |   Apple
2       |   Banana
3       |   Pinneaple
```

I want to add column called 'Display' which contain both data from Code and Description, I plan to use this SQL `SELECT "NAME" ||'-' || DESCRIPTION FROM M_STOCKCODE_JB` so it will generated like this :

```
                M_StockCode_JB
    ------------------------------------------
    Code    |   Description    |   Display
    1       |   Apple          |   1-Apple
    2       |   Banana         |   2-Banana
    3       |   Pineapple      |   3-Pineapple
```

How can I insert to Display column as I add column Code and Description ?

Comment: May i know What version of oracle you are using?

Comment: @Tarun I am using Oracle 12c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Display column allways contain only `"NAME" ||'-' || DESCRIPTION`, and you are using Oracle 11G or higher, you may create virtual column

```
ALTER TABLE M_StockCode_JB ADD (Display AS (NAME ||'-' || DESCRIPTION))
```

In any version you may create view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_M_StockCode_JB AS
SELECT "NAME" ||'-' || DESCRIPTION FROM M_STOCKCODE_JB
```

If column need to be updatable, then you need real column with trigger

```
ALTER TABLE M_StockCode_JB ADD (Display VARCHAR2(4000));
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER M_StockCode_JB_trig
  BEFORE
    INSERT ON M_StockCode_JB 
    FOR EACH ROW    
BEGIN
  :new.Display = :new.NAME ||'-' || :new.DESCRIPTION;
END;
/
```